# Migra Doc PDF Footer Styling

Tags: c#, pdf, report, migradoc

I have a footer that goes on the right and left of each page. Each Paragraph in the footer contains 2 lines of text. What I want is to add a horizontal line between the 2 lines of text in the footer.

Here is the code for adding the footer.

```
 private void AddFooterData(Section section) {
        // add prepared by. approved by etc

        var rightFooterSection = new Paragraph {
            Format = { Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right }
        };
        rightFooterSection.AddText("Prepared By Eng: " + _preparedBy);
        rightFooterSection.AddLineBreak();

        rightFooterSection.AddText("Page ");
        rightFooterSection.AddPageField();
        rightFooterSection.AddText(" / ");
        rightFooterSection.AddNumPagesField();
        section.Footers.Primary.Add(rightFooterSection);

        var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        var leftSection = new Paragraph {
            Format = { Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left }
        };
        leftSection.AddText("Approved By: " + _approvedBy);

        leftSection.AddLineBreak();
        leftSection.AddText(date);
        section.Footers.Primary.Add(leftSection);

    }
```

here is a picture of the desired footer outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this figured on my own.
Create a table containing 2 columns with a width same as the page,
Create 2 rows
on the top row, set the bottom border to be visible.
align text in each row, so left column would be aligned left, right column would be aligned right

```
private void AddFooterData(Section section) {

        var rightFooterSection = new Paragraph {
            Format = { Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right }
        };
        rightFooterSection.AddText("Prepared By Eng: " + _preparedBy);

        var rightFooterPagePar = new Paragraph {
             Format = { Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right }
         };
        rightFooterPagePar.AddText("Page ");
        rightFooterPagePar.AddPageField();
        rightFooterPagePar.AddText("/");
        rightFooterPagePar.AddNumPagesField();


        var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        var leftSection = new Paragraph {
            Format = { Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left }
        };
        var leftDateSection = new Paragraph {
            Format = { Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left }
        };
        leftSection.AddText("Approved By: " + _approvedBy);
        leftDateSection.AddText(date);
        var footerTable = section.Footers.Primary.AddTable();
        var col1 = footerTable.AddColumn();
        col1.Width = "5.5in";

        var col2 = footerTable.AddColumn();
        col2.Width = "5.5in";
        var row1 = footerTable.AddRow();
        row1[0].Add(leftSection);
        row1[1].Add(rightFooterSection);
        row1.Borders.Bottom.Visible = true;
        row1.Borders.Bottom.Width = "0.10cm";
        var row2 = footerTable.AddRow();
        row2[0].Add(leftDateSection);
        row2[1].Add(rightFooterPagePar);
```